# Matlab double function outputs infinity when taking a big number of type "sym"

Tags: matlab, double

This is literally the number I obtain (from symsum function), which is of type sym:

a=328791078344903739363762093060350430076929707044786898291940722052812676355129485878814911641516759087483581972443760841410582114920781832660013389681326267351368505696628653562484228680842650173635989588528021721039959787053654401351638478786763875479187208098871238084448485336138651690856082810553570419028927840285091142054111375001

I would like to make mathematical operations (in particular, take a natural log) on this number and so want to transform it to double, however the output from double(a) is simply "Inf". How to go about this problem and convert it from "sum" to a numeric type?

Comment: Why not perform all of your mathematical operations in the symbolic domain and only convert to `double` at the very end? If it still overflows to `Inf` then double precision floating-point may not be right for this calculation or you may need to adjust other things.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is ~3.3x10<sup>335</sup> but the largest number that can be represented by MATLAB's double precision floating point numbers is ~1.8x10<sup>308</sup> (see the output of `realmax`). Converting your number to double precision causes overflow because the number is larger than can be represented so MATLAB just returns `Inf`.

For an exhaustive overview of floating point representations and arithmetic, you can check out this [PDF](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Can you count the digits and insert a decimal point before converting to double?

If so, take advantage of the fact that the natural log of a number that overflows may not itself overflow.

Using "^" for power, you can represent your number as `3.28791078344903739363762093060350430076929707044786898291940722052812676355129485878814911641516759087483581972443760841410582114920781832660013389681326267351368505696628653562484228680842650173635989588528021721039959787053654401351638478786763875479187208098871238084448485336138651690856082810553570419028927840285091142054111375001 * (10 ^ 335)`.

The decimal log of `(10^335)` is `335`. Its natural log is `335*log(10)`.

The natural log of the original number is:

```
log(3.287910783449037393637620930603504300769297070447868982919407220528) 
+ 335*log(10)
```

All inputs, intermediate results, and the final result of this calculation are in the double range.